# Django: TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to load a template, but it seems to keep searching for a template in a path that does not exist. I'm looking to load `visit_form.html`, but it keeps looking in `clincher/visit_form`, and cannot seem to get rid of the "`clincher/`" part of the template location. It was previously set up this way, but changed it when I moved my template locations to the respective app.

Template Url:
`<td><a href="{% url 'clincher:visit_form' main.id %}"  role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">New Consult</a></td>`

Main/Urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from clincher import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('clincher/', include('clincher.urls'), name='clincher'),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='clincher/templates/')),
]
```

Clincher/Urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.urls import path

app_name = 'clincher'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('main/', views.MainListView.as_view(), name='main'),
    path('main/<int:pk>', views.MainDetailView.as_view(), name='main_detail'),
    path('visit/add/<int:pk>', views.VisitCreate.as_view(), name='visit_form'),
]
```

Views.py

```
class VisitCreate( CreateView):
    login_url = '/login/'
    redirect_field_name = 'index'
    model = Visit
    fields = [ 'visit_label', 'visit_type', 'visit_progress_notes']
    template = 'templates/visit_form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.fk_visit_user = self.request.user
        form.instance.fk_visit_main = Main.object.get(self.kwargs['pk'])
        return super(VisitCreate, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('main_detail', args={'pk': self.object.id})
```

Settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

INSTALLED_APPS = [

    'clincher.apps.clincherConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'accounts',
]

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

And finally, my Traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/clincher/visit/add/2

Django Version: 2.0.4
Python Version: 3.6.4
Installed Applications:
['clincher.apps.clincherConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'accounts']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: /Users/nrsmoll/PycharmProjects/clincher/templates/clincher/visit_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/nrsmoll/PycharmProjects/clincher/clincher/templates/clincher/visit_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/clincher/visit_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/templates/clincher/visit_form.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: /Users/nrsmoll/PycharmProjects/clincher/accounts/templates/clincher/visit_form.html (Source does not exist)

Traceback:

File "/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  35.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  158.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = response.render()

File "/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  81.         template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)

File "/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in resolve_template
  63.             return select_template(template, using=self.using)

File "/Users/nrsmoll/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in select_template
   47.         raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)

Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /clincher/visit/add/2
Exception Value: clincher/visit_form.html
```

All I need is to get rid of the "clincher" part of the "clincher/visit_form.html".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have most likely put your `template` in the following path:

```
.../PycharmProject/clincher/templates/visit_form.html
```

If you add another folder to your directory to store your template files the way Djanog expects them to be stored it should work.  That path is:

```
.../PycharmProject/clincher/templates/clincher/visit_form.html
```

In your URL, Django will put your app name at the front.

If you don't want to change your directory structure you can replace your `'DIRS'` value as follows {I got this to work on my mac - can't test on PC}:

```
# Current
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],

# Fixed
'DIRS': ['templates'],
```

This should attempt to look for templates under your app.  Having said that, this is not the way Django was designed.  See the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/templates/#usage).  If you scroll down a little way you'll see a couple of examples how how to change the the DIRS list.

```
#From the docs
'DIRS': [
    '/home/html/example.com',
    '/home/html/default',
],
```

But beware - it's better to use relative path references and not hard coded paths.

Comment: So I cannot change the folder location? Is there any way of closing the folder location, so I don't have to have that extra folder location?

Answer (score 0):

Your general schema seemed a bit unclear / untidy to me.

Your visit_form is under your Clincher, so it is very normal for the system to look for clincher/visit/add/pk . Also you're pointing this url on your html template:

```
{% url 'clincher:visit_form' main.id %}"
```

. So, you should create your *visit_form.html* within this the "templates" folder under clicnher, then.

And in your view you can type a better success_url instead of *redirect_field_name = 'index'*.

For example:

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('clincher:visit_form')
```

Plus, your index in url is empty. ?